# How to rename a folder on OneDrive using Windows Phone API?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, onedrive

This is how I was creating a folder on OneDrive using Windows Phone API.

```
    public async Task<string> CreateSkyDriveFolder()
    {
        string folderId = null;
        var opResult = await Client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files?filter=folders");
        dynamic result = opResult.Result;

        foreach (dynamic folder in result.data)
        {
            if (folder.name.ToLowerInvariant().Trim() == skyDriveFolderName.ToLowerInvariant().Trim())
            {
                folderId = folder.id;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (folderId == null)
        {
            var folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            folderData.Add("name", skyDriveFolderName);
            opResult = await Client.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);
            result = opResult.Result;
            folderId = result.id;
        }
    }
```

But now, I just want to replace a folder name 'OldFolder' on OneDrive to 'NewFolder'. How can I do this using API?

Any help will much be appreciated. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Each folder in the OneDrive API is considered to be an "item".
And each item can be updated with a new name.

These rows should update the item with id "folderId" and give it the new name "NewFolder".

```
var Client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
  new HttpMethod("PATCH"), 
  String.Format("/drive/items/{0}", folderId)
);

var renameInstruction = new StringContent("{\"name\":\"NewFolder\"}");
request.Content = renameInstruction;

var opResult = await Client.SendAsync(request);
```

Tested on my private OneDrive folder using the [OneDrive console](https://apigee.com/OneDrive/embed/console/OneDrive?apig_cc=1).

API source: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/items/update.md

Let me know if anything is unclear or strange in any way. Have a marvelous day!

Comment: Thanks Fabian, but how can I use in API for Windows Phone?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie I'll look into the API differences a bit later. The code works on WP10, didn't notice you were working on WP8. My bad :)
It should be the same general idea, but maybe a few differences in API naming.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie I checked now, and it seems like everything I used is available on Windows Phone 8. Is there a specific line or thing that you're unable to reproduce? I guess you already have the token stuff working since you're able to create folders already? :)